# QField numbers written in grey

Tags: qfield, text, font

When I use QField, all the numbers are written in grey color (not in black like for letters).
How to change that, to have all the texts (numbers and letters) written in black ?

[image]

Comment: Does it happen only with numbers? In my projects both numbers and letters are grey untill you don't switch to the 'edit' mode.

Comment: For me, it happens only with numbers (you can see that on the image)